# Converting Java to Lua

Tags: java, lua

I'm a low-level Java user, and now I'm trying to learn Lua... and I just really don't understand, and the things written about it just confuse me more. If someone could convert this short piece from Java to Lua, then I would be able to compare them and figure out what's equivalent to what. I would be very greatful. So help, please?

```
  public String IllumByDay(double cycle) {
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

        for (double dayCounter = 0; dayCounter <= cycle - 1; dayCounter++) {
            double illum = 0.5 * (1 + Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (dayCounter / cycle - 0.25)));
            String roundedIllum = myFormatter.format(illum * 100);
            System.out.println("Day " + (int) (dayCounter + 1) + ": " + roundedIllum + "%");
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. this is not a code translation service. Lua syntax is super simple. you are just too lazy and hope that someone will spoon-feed you the solution... please read [ask]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because code translation requests are off-topic

Comment: Which part confuses you? Can't be all of it, because if a normal `for` loop is confusing, then you have much to learn before attempting something like this. Also, hopefully operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` are not confusing either.

Answer (score 2):

Let's be helpful, eh?

You could start with something like this:

```
function IllumByDay(cycle)
    for dayCounter = 0, cycle-1 do
        local illum = 0.5 * (1.0 + math.sin(2.0*math.pi*(dayCounter/cycle - 0.25)))
        local roundedIllum = string.format('%.2f', illum * 100.0)
        print(string.format("Day %d: %s%", dayCounter+1, roundedIllum))
    end
end
```